# What's the correct way of moving data from one table to another?

Tags: c#, sql

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string del = "Delete From Temp_Items";
        string mov = "INSERT into Items (Serial, Date, Location, Type, Condition, Color, Loaned_To, Product_NumberREF, Department) Select (Serial, Date, Location, Type, Condition, Color, Loaned_To, Product_NumberREF, Department) From TempItems";

        SqlCommand Delete = new SqlCommand(del, conn);
        SqlCommand move = new SqlCommand(mov, conn);
        move.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

With this code I'm attempting to move all data in a table to another table, then deleting the data that was copied over. How do I correctly move the data without disruption because currently I have a problem with the 4th line of code. It says there is a error.

the error is = Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: The columns you select doesn't match the number of columns you're trying to insert.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to Include its c#

Comment: I keep getting this error"  Incorrect syntax near ','.  "

Comment: You have too many parameters in the SQL. ie: ", Temp)"

Answer (score 0):

The best way to move data from one table to another, is simply use SELECT INTO, and later delete the data from the first table...

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Example...

```
    SELECT *
    INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
    FROM table1;

DELETE * FROM table1;
```

EDIT:
You can also of course DROP the original table, which means you've moved all the data from one table to another completely!

```
DROP table1;
```